# Does the condition of this theorem need continuous differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm reading the book, *Analysis from its History*, from E. Hairer and G. Wanner. Precisely, I'm reading the french version from 2001, *L'analyse au fil de l'histoire*. The following theorem is given:

> If a function $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and
>   $f'(x_0)>0$ then, it exists $\delta>0$ such that:
>
> - $f(x)>f(x_0)$ for all $x$ such that $x_0<x<x_0+\delta$,
> - $f(x)<f(x_0)$ for all $x$ such that $x_0-\delta<x<x_0$.
>
> If the function reach a maximum (or minimum) at $x_0$, then
>   $f'(x_0)=0$.

But then, they give the following counterexample $f(x)=x+x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

I think that there is an error in the theorem and that the condition should be that $f$ is **continuously differentiable**. Can you confirm that?

Comment: You need only differentiability **at** $x_0$. The "counterexample" isn't even continuous at $0$. If one makes it $f(0) = 0$, then you have $f'(0) = 1$. The assertion still holds, but the function is not monotonic on any interval containing $0$.

Comment: @angryavian No, not continuous at $0.$ The limit of $f$ is $0$ but $f(0)=1.$

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it's $f(0)=0$.

Comment: This still isn't a counterexample. For all $x>0$ we have $f(x)>f(0)$ and for $x<0$ we have $f(x)<f(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need continuous differentiability, the theorem holds under the assumption that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$. It need not be differentiable, nor even continuous, anywhere else.

The "counterexample" is not a counterexample to the given theorem, but to the stronger assertion that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $f$ is monotonic on $(x_0 - \delta, x_0+\delta)$. For *that* assertion, you need continuous differentiability on a neighbourhood of $x_0$ (or the hypothesis that $f' \geqslant 0$ on a neighbourhood of $x_0$).

Comment: You are exactly right, it's a counterexample of monotonicity.